# How to display build warnings in TFS alert email

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-alerts

The TFS alert email for completed builds contains a list of build errors.
We are using an on-premises TFS 2018 server (a.k.a. Azure DevOps Server).
[image]

However, I would like to see the list of build *warnings*, too.

I already read the numerous posts on modifying `BuildCompletedEvent.xsl` to tweak the appearance of the email and that all works well. Using the hack below to get the full XML input I found out that it does in fact not contain the build warnings.

Is there a way to modify/hack the TFS service that creates the XML input for the alert emails?

The information about this on the internet is a mash of bits and pieces for XAML-builds, pre-TFS-2010, post-TFS2010 servers, and Azure devops server/services with lots of dead links and loose ends.

I feel like I basically had to reimplement almost the entire email alerting stuff of the TFS server if I went down the road to create a custom subscriber for the `BuildCompletedEvent` event (a.k.a. `BuildCompletionEvent`).

So is there a reasonably *economic*, (i.e. simple) way to get this little extra information into the TFS alert emails?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <textarea>
      <xsl:copy-of select="/" />
    </textarea>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There are 10,000 warnings. I'd posit that is a clear indication that no one actually cares about them. Are you really going to notice if the number of warnings goes from 10,000 to 10,001? Even if you had warnings displayed in the build results, it would just be a massive wall of warnings that's too large to do anything but ignore.

Comment: Well - I was contemplating whether or not this objection would arise. Of course we don't usually have that many errors and warnings. I deliberately compiled a shelve set with a few errors and /Wall, which triggers a lot of warnings in the standard library headers; just to have something to work on. Just for the record: limiting the list of entries to - say - 100 each would be step 2.